# kill process, start process

Tags: vbscript, process, kill

I'm looking for a VBScript that when a user clicks on it, it will check and see if the user is running the process `winver.exe`. If the process `winver.exe` is running under that user it will end the process, if the process `winver.exe` is not running it will continue on with the script below.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell")
const iHideWindow = 0

objShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\wfcrun32.exe"" ""C:\APP.ica"""

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "winver", 0
```

Answer (score 0):

WMI is probably the best way to handle this:

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
user   = LCase(net.UserName)
domain = LCase(net.UserDomain)

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='winver.exe'"
For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  p.GetOwner u, d
  If LCase(u) = user And LCase(d) = domain Then p.Terminate
Next
```